# <Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix. in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, uitableview

I have tableViewCell with button to load a photo from imagePickerController.

Here is code for imagePickerController. I send tableViewCell index as a tag to button to find out on which cell this button was clicked. Then when user selects an image from gallery it sets this image to background of loading button and saves this image to my array of selected images.

```
// get photo function
func getPhotoFromGallery(sender: UIButton){
    cellTag = sender.tag
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: cellTag!, inSection: 0)) as! QuestionTableViewCell
    cell.photoImageView.setBackgroundImage(chosenImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    photos[cellTag!] = chosenImage
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath I check image in my array to be default or selected by user and set it to background of button.

```
// imageView style and target
cell.photoLoadingButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
cell.photoLoadingButton.clipsToBounds = true
cell.photoLoadingButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.photoLoadingButton.addTarget(self, action: "getPhotoFromGallery:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

// set photo to imageView if exists else - default
if photos[indexPath.row] == UIImage(named: "camera")! {
    cell.photoLoadingButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "camera")!, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
else {
    cell.photoLoadingButton.setBackgroundImage(photos[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

And everything works fine but i think my method is bad =(

Then, when I select a few images in tableView and scroll the table I'm getting this message in log: ": CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.". It appears exactly when the new cell with uploaded image is shown.